# how to give the spacing between each cell in a table and make it like a different making a table

Tags: php, html

how to give the spacing between each cell in a table and make it like a different making a table in HTML.
i want to  make it like a cells becoming table by combining it all together. 
code:
like shown tabs in the www.quickr.com

```
 <table class="table" width=100% cellspacing="3px" style="border-spacing:10px; ">
    <tr>
                        <!--<td bgcolor="#FF0000">-->
                        <!--<td bgcolor="#F3E9AF" height="200px" width="350px" style="padding: 74px;">-->

                        <td style="padding: -7px;">
                        <!--<td bgcolor="#99E7F7">-->
                            <div class="column col-md-4">
                            <div id="c-830" class="block">
                            <h4><img src="images/categories/rent_7.png" height=110 width=150 style="margin-top: -5px">
<a href="#">                            
                            <strong style="color: #343434;">Rent</strong>
                            </a>
                            </h4>
                            <div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                        </td>
 <td style="padding: -35px;">
                            <!--<td bgcolor="#004488">-->
                            <div class="column col-md-4">
                            <div id="c-362" class="block">
                            <h4><img src="images/categories/buy_6.png" height=110 width=150 style="margin-top: -3px">
                            <a href="#">
                            <strong style="color: #343434;">Buy</strong>
                            </a>
                            </h4>
                            <div>
                            </div>
                            </div>                                       </div>                                             
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding: -23px;">
                            <div class="column col-md-4">
                            <div id="c-833" class="block">
                            <h4><img src="images/categories/sell_tag.png" height=110 width=150 style="margin-top: -5px">
                            <a href="#">
                            <strong style="color: #343434;">Sell</strong>
                            </a>
                            </h4>
                            <div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `cellspacing` doesn't take the value `XXpx` but rather `XX` at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to give a table name  and then you could add for td/tr in css a padding or border-spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .. by using  cellpadding="value" & cellspacing="value"

`Check this`: [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rb091fea/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this .. by using

```
<table cellpadding="15" cellspacing="15">
   <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```